# How does SRP prevent man-in-middle attacks?

Tags: passwords, authentication

[SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) is designed to resist both active and passive attacks, how does SRP prevent man-in-middle and packet modification attacks?

Comment: What do SRP mean? please give us reference or whole words!

Comment: @F.Hauri [Secure Remote Password (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) is a well-known protocol. I guess OP assumed that most people would know what it is.

Comment: If you read this page (with some elementary cryptography knowledge) you will get answers to most of your question : http://srp.stanford.edu/ndss.html

Comment: @Polynomial Sorry, I've heard about blackberry's *`Server Routing Protocol`* and Microsoft`s *`Security Rollup Package`* for sample, who both could be subject of discuss on http://security.stackexchange.com... Anyway for disembiguation and readability, remember acronym meaning at least once in a question is **not** too mutch!

Comment: @user20851 yes I read that.

Answer (score 4):

SRP is a [Password-Authenticated Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) algorithm. One flawed but simple way to see it is that client and server share a secret, on which the algorithm expands; an attacker trying a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) does not know the secret, and cannot successfully impersonate either the client or the server (or both, in a true MitM).

What I describe above is "just" using the password as a (pre-shared) key. PAKE algorithms go a bit further, with a lot of mathematics, to be able to tolerate a shared secret of **low entropy** (namely, the password): an attacker observing the exchange, or even trying to impersonate the client or the server, does not learn anything which would allow him to "try passwords at home" (i.e. he does not get out of the algorithm a hash of the password), something called an *offline dictionary attack*. This is done with a subtle dance with a classical key exchange and a commitment.

Simplest to understand is [Encrypted Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_key_exchange) in which the exchange is a normal [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), but client and server both "encrypt" what they send with the password. The "encryption" algorithm must be such that decrypting with the wrong password still yields something which looks like a normal DH message (another element of the group). An attacker who wants to run an offline dictionary attack will want to "retarget" a given exchange, by doing something which amounts to "let's imagine that for this past exchange, I had used password *P*". With EKE, any "retarget" with another password than the one he indeed used leaves the attacker outside of the DH key exchange, preventing him from obtaining the DH session key and testing his password hypothesis.

(I said "simplest to understand", not "simple". It takes some time to cryptographers to wrap their mind around what really happens in PAKE algorithms, which a friend of mine had once described as "a small miracle".)

**Anyway**, a PAKE algorithm is a key exchange and results in a shared key *K*. It is still up to client and server to use *K* to encrypt and protect subsequent data packets, using the usual paraphernalia of symmetric encryption and MAC. This is why SRP is best used [as part of SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054), the latter providing the mechanisms for tunneling long streams of data.

Comment: Can I claims that SRP can prevent attacker who trying impersonate either client or server. But it doesn't protect the data subsequently. Attacker still can perform packet modification attack? Using SRP/TLS, TLS will create a secure channel.

Comment: If the exchanged data will be encrypted using the shared key, it only prevent the mitm attack but not integrity right?

Comment: SRP is a key exchange algorithm; it establishes a shared key. SRP does not deal with "data". To protect data, you need a transmission _protocol_ which will use a key exchange algorithm at its start (e.g. SRP) and then other algorithms for encryption and integrity of the actual data which is to be transmitted. TLS+SRP is such a protocol (and it applies both encryption and MAC on the data, so integrity is protected as well).

Comment: Yes I knew this just, said if not using the TLS, but the subsequently exchanged data will be encrypted using some of the encryption algorithm.